# HTML/Unicode entity for math reciprocal/multiplicative inverse

Tags: html, unicode

Is there a Unicode or HTML entity for displaying the reciprocal/multiplicative inverse operator? I'm creating a calculator and need to display this operator on the associated button. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean? Could you include an image of what you are looking (or a TeX/LaTeX version).

Comment: It's the number that would need to be multiplied by the given number for the result to be 1. Essentially I think it's 1/X where X is the number on the calculator display. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A poor man solution:

`\u00b9\u2044\u2093` which gives `¹⁄ₓ` (or in proportional font: ¹⁄ₓ) or `\u215F\u2093"` which gives `⅟ₓ` (proportional font: ⅟ₓ).

I do not know any better variant.